# How do I draw a tree with two lines in a single node? Using tikz package!

Tags: tikz-trees

I would like to use `\usepackage{tikz-qtree}` to draw a tree. The code is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=2pt]
 \Tree [.TP 
        [.DP {\O}
          [.D' [.D {\O}  ] 
            [.NP [.N' [.N Andy ]]]]] 
        [.T' 
          [.T $[past]$\\$[EPP]$\\$[3sg]$ ] 
        [.VP 
           [.V' 
            [.V leave\\ ]]]]]       
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{exe}
```

The result is shown below. But I do not want `[past]`, `[EPP]` and `[3sg]` to be the same line. I tried to add `\\` between them, but it only changes this part into multi branches tree. Are there any mistakes? Thank you very much for your help!!!

[image]

Comment: Unrelated, but it's linguistically incorrect to have a line between the terminal node labels and the words (i.e., there should be no line between N and *Andy*, or V and *leave*, etc.)

Comment: Thank you so much~

Comment: Yes, I know that. I just did not know how to delete that line. hahaha. But now I know. Thank you very much for pointing out that! I really learned a lot. XD

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:**

The same result as with `tikz-qtree` can be achieved by use of the `forest` package with ˙linguistics` option. It is designed for such cases as is present in question. Using it, the MWE can be write as follows:

```
\documentclass[margin=3.14159mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
                
\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
[TP
    [DP 
        [\O]
        [D'
            [D 
                [\O]
            ]
            [NP
                [N'
                    [N
                        [Andy ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
    [T'
        [T 
            [{$[past]$}\\{$[EPP]$}\\{$[3sg]$} ]
        ]
        [VP
           [V'
                [V
                    [leave]
                ]
           ]
        ]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

The same result can be obtained with use of the "pure"  `forest` package. In this case we need to define specification `for tree` as follows:

```
\documentclass[margin=3.14159mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
                
\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
% nodes
    align=center,
    inner ysep=0pt,
% tree
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
            }
[TP
% body of tree, the same as before
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note*:  @ Alan Munn, thank you very much for your comments!

Comment: If you load `forest` with the `[linguistics]` option you'll get this format by default and won't need to specify it per tree.

Comment: @AlanMunn, you are right. After posting I start to read manual again (and not jet finished) and recognize, that there is simpler way as I show in answer. I will make an addendum asap.

Comment: Surely it would make sense to make the `[linguistics]` option (which you forgot to add, btw :) ) as the main answer with the per-tree option as the alternative?

Comment: @AlanMunn, good point. I will edit my answer again ...

Answer (score 2):

You can use the option `align=center` to activate line breaks.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=2pt]
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={anchor=north,align=center}}
 \Tree [.TP 
        [.DP {\O}
          [.D' [.D {\O}  ] 
            [.NP [.N' [.N Andy ]]]]] 
        [.T' 
          [.T $[past]$\\$[EPP]$\\$[3sg]$ ] 
        [.VP 
           [.V' 
            [.V leave\\ ]]]]]       
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

<sub>(H/T to Alan Munn for suggesting the `\tikzset` approach.)</sub>

Comment: Simpler is to add to your preamble: `\tikzset{every tree node/.style={anchor=north,align=center}}` and then you don't need to use `\node` in your tree.

Comment: @AlanMunn: Thanks. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: If you do it in the preamble of the document, then it will apply to all trees. No need to add it to each tree.

Comment: Wow!! Thank you very much!!!